# __rmatmul__ not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, operator-overloading

I have a custom class for which I want to implement the possibility of using the matrix multiplication `@` operator.

In my class the `__rmatmul__` method is defined and if I have e.g. an instance `molecule` the following works:

```
molecule.__rmatmul__( np.diag([1, 1, -1]))
```

But the following returns a `ValueError`:

```
np.diag([1, 1, -1]) @ molecule
```

I do not want to clump up this question with the code for the `class` definition. But If necessary I will provide it.

EDIT:
I made a small test, with a minimal class to narrow the problem down:

```
class minimal:
     def __rmatmul__(self, other):
         return 1

     def __rmul__(self, other):
         return 2

test = minimal()

1 * test
```

returns 2 as expected.

```
np.zeros([3,3]) @ test
```

returns now a `TypeError`. Which is a bit inconsistent for me.

Comment: If a value error is raised, that probably means that the Numpy implementation did not return a `NotImplemented` sentinel. Python checks the left-hand op *first*, unless the right-hand op type is a subclass of the left-hand.

Comment: Try `np.diag([1, 1, -1]).__matmul__(molecule)` to verify.

Comment: Yes, it gives a ``ValueError``. Is there a possibility to properly circumvent this?

Comment: No, you'll have to file an issue with the numpy project to have that fixed.

Comment: The [numpy source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/numpy/core/src/multiarray/number.c#L101-L122) appears to imply that just implementing a `__rmatmul__` should be enough. Did you implement it on the *class* or on the instance?

Comment: It is in the ``class`` definition. I made a test with a minimal class now, that is included in the updated question.

Comment: I'd file this as a bug with the project. Having the mcve here is excellent. I certainly can reproduce this (`np.zeros([3, 3]).__matmul__(test)` raises a `TypeError`, it doesn't return `NotImplemented`), and `test.__rmatmul__(np.zeros([3, 3]))` returns `1` as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What does mcve mean? If you write an answer summarising, I will accept it.

Comment: mcve == [mcve], something to reproduce the issue with concisely.

Comment: Ah, looking at [Array and \_\_rmul\_\_ operator in Python Numpy](//stackoverflow.com/q/38229953) this appears to be a deliberate choice; only subclasses of `ndarray` are going to be supported.

Comment: Yeah, this is, I am afraid, by design and the question is a duplicate (what applies to `__mul__` applies to `__matmul__` here too).

Comment: It definitely is a duplicate. I just searched for ``__rmatmul__`` in the beginning. It also explains why I get once a ``TypeError`` and once a ``ValueError``. My minimal class is treated as scalar; my real class I am working on has ``__getitem__`` and similar methods implemented. I guess numpy tries to treat those instances as arrays.